# How do random spawns work?

Tags: fallout-4

I was level 26 in Fallout (few days ago, now level 31) and I decided to have a chance at getting the X-01 power armour and visited a building near the Boston Custom House building that has a power armour spawn inside. I beat those annoying robots with two fat man shells and I opened the door to the suit. Unluckily, I only got a T-60...

I realized that I needed to be level 27 so I loaded my last save (where I did not spawn the sentry bot and assaultron) at the entrance to the roof. Does anybody know if I will get the same T-60 armour if I go back at level 31 now?

Comment: Which building is this? I'm looking to finish my set of x-01 as well.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill It is near the Boston Custom House building.

Answer (score 1):

Well its never guaranteed which armor will spawn but sounds like you should have a chance at the x-01 armor if you go now that you are lvl 31 now. Not 100% sure because of the spot you reloaded from which is why you should do the saves a decent distance away when you are trying to get something specific from a random spawn like that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the armor is generated the moment you enter the building - so if you've entered the building at level 26 and then left it (or loaded the save from the time after entering the building) it will stay as t-60, otherwise the RNG will roll again giving you a good chance to get the X1

Comment: When you load it resets the RNG, and the loot is calculated when you enter the area, so this should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given Fallout 4 is reworked from the Skyrim system, you can most likely rest for 30 days in game and trigger a map reset.

Save the game far away, trigger the spawn, and see if you get the X-01.  If not, go to a far away place, rest for 30+ days straight, and try again and see if the area has reset for a new spawn.

I'm not certain if this is a one-time event though, but it is worth trying.